# PROBLEMA DE INSTALAÇÃO WAMPSERVER

Tags: wampserver

[image: Erro de instalação]
Olá, estou querendo instalar o wampserver, porém sempre aparece este erro. Alguém conhece? Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Aperta em < Back e mostre a tela em que você digitou o bendito caminho.

Answer (score 0):

No caso, é por que você está instalando uma extensão do Wamp, no caso do MariaDB, (pode verificar no titulo do Form aberto). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580223/error-when-installing-wampserver, o mesmo erro, porém o usuário estava instalando a extensão do PHP. Baixe a partir desse site: http://www.wampserver.com/en/, na parte de baixo da página, tem o botão de download.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/173914)

Comment: Ah, obrigado pela dica!